# How can I restart the timer, after it was cancelled?

Tags: java, android, service, timer, broadcastreceiver

I've got this service, which starts a timer, whenever said service also starts. The idea is that, if the user manually turns on the screen (i.e. the app. enters in the "counter" BroadcastReceiver), the timer gets cancelled. Otherwise, if the timer finishes by itself, the service will automatically stop (via onDestroy, of course).

My problem comes when I want to restart the service, WITHOUT killing the app. first. If I simply input a new number of seconds and start the service, I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled`

How can I get rid of said problem?

MainService:

```
public class MainService extends Service {

static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.vladpintea.friendsbeforecents.displayevent";
Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intentForStars;

String usedTimer;
long interval;

TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() { public void run() { stopSelf(); } };
Timer myTimer = new Timer();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(MainService.this, "Service, Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    intentForStars = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

    registerReceiver(counter, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
}

private BroadcastReceiver counter = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        myTimer.cancel();

        NotificationManager notify_manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent_main_activity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pending_intent_main_activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent_main_activity, 0);
        Notification notification_popup = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Friends Before Cents")
                .setContentText("Oh, no! You've Lost. Try Again?")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_sentiment_very_dissatisfied_white_48dp)
                .setContentIntent(pending_intent_main_activity)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        notify_manager.notify(0, notification_popup);

        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 30000);
    }
};

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(MainService.this, "Service, Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try { usedTimer = intent.getStringExtra("timer"); } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {}
    try { interval = Long.parseLong(usedTimer); } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
    myTimer.schedule(myTask, interval * 1000);

    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); }
};

public void addStars() { sendBroadcast(intentForStars); }

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(counter);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 30000);

    NotificationManager notify_manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent_main_activity = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pending_intent_main_activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent_main_activity, 0);
    Notification notification_popup = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Friends Before Cents")
            .setContentText("Congrats! You've Won Some Coins.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_sentiment_very_satisfied_white_48dp)
            .setContentIntent(pending_intent_main_activity)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notify_manager.notify(0, notification_popup);

    addStars();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not, the Doc reference states that once cancelled you need to create a new instance...

the [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()):

> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a
>   repeating timer task absolutely guarantees that the timer task will
>   not run again.

So basically after cancel you need a **new** one...